# Como referenciar no texto LATEX sem parênteses

Tags: latex

Estou trabalhando meu TCC usando o ShareLatex e um template da minha universidade. Já configurei o arquivo `.bib` e consigo realizar citações utilizando o `\cite{}`. Mas desta forma ele sempre gera por exemplo:

`segundo (Fulano, 2012)`

Qual comando devo utilizar para gerar referências desta forma:

`segundo Fulano (2012)`

Existem casos que utilizar o primeiro formato faz mais sentido, porém para a coesão do texto as vezes o segundo caso me parece mais apropriado.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar as variações do `\cite`, no seu caso acredito que o `\citet{}` (citação textual) resolveria, algo como:

```
\citet{Erdos65} --> Erdős et al. (1965)
```

Tem outras variações, pode dar uma olhada na [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies).

**EDIT:** É necessário importar o pacote `natbib`, usando:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Comment: Esse comando não auto completou no ShareLatex, preciso fazer algo para utiliza-lo?